# how to get actual width of an element with floating element on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the width of a paragraph element like in the pic.[image]

I want to get the width of the content in the red box, while when I'm using $("p").width(), I got 800, but there is an image float on it's right side.

How can I get the ACTUAL width of this paragraph?

The page url is : http://www.businessinsider.com/healthy-at-work-without-a-standing-desk-2014-12?utm_content=&utm_medium=email&utm_source=alerts&nr_email_referer=1

Comment: try wrapping the contents of the paragraph in a span and see what span width returns.  can use `wrapInner()` if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your paragraph in css

```
p{
   display: table;
}
```

in js use

```
$('p').outerWidth();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oed918dq/) tested in chrome and ie